# C# Universal app crash after startup, but only from store installation

Tags: c#, windbg, universal

I'm having an issue with an universal application.
I'm trying to make it work since 7 days (and nights ;)

I've develop my app on my dev PC without big troubles.
The app works well in debug and release mode (also with .NET Native pre compilation)

But when deploying the app on the store (or with side loading), it crashes directly after splashscreen !

I got the dump file a used windbg with pde extension to understand the issue...and here am I.
I don't catch the real issue, it seems that it's linked with xaml strings and a null pointer exception. 
The exception is : `KERNELBASE!BasepIsSecureProcess`.
After digging on this with windbg, I fall into :  `combase!roOriginateLanguageException+0x57`...

You'll find bellow the report from windbg.

If you could help me in that trap...

Here is the report :

```
=========================================================================================

PDE v10.0 - Copyright 2015 Andrew Richards

=========================================================================================

Stowed Exception Array @ 0x0000020320afe850



Stowed Exception #1 @ 0x0000020320af9f68

        0x80004003 (FACILITY_NULL - Default): E_POINTER - Pointer that is not valid



        Stack      : 0x2032305d3c0

               7ffee14a76a7 combase!RoOriginateLanguageException+0x57

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for coreclr.dll -

               7ffea0ceeb20 coreclr!GetCLRRuntimeHost+0x8a3bc

               7ffea0e1d63b coreclr!GetCLRRuntimeHost+0x1b8ed7

               7ffe413108c4



Stowed Exception #2 @ 0x00000203230586d0

        0x80004003 (FACILITY_NULL - Default): E_POINTER - Pointer that is not valid



        Stack      : 0x2032306c178

               7ffec7c75b02 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkApplication::MainASTAInitialize+0x12a

               7ffec7c75723 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkView::Initialize+0x73

               7ffedcc298e8 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::CreateAndInitializeFrameworkView+0xb8

               7ffedcc44e0a twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClass<Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil>::RuntimeClass<Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil>+0x1a6

               7ffedeac9087 SHCore!??$MakeAndInitialize@VCClosableStreamWrapper@@UIStream@@PEAU2@$$T@Details@WRL@Microsoft@@YAJPEAPEAUIStream@@$$QEAPEAU3@$$QEA$$T@Z+0x27b

               7ffedf898102 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22

               7ffee1b2c574 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

Cheers,

Ricardo

Comment: ask Andrew via the mail adress posted here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools

Comment: I found a workaround to avoid startup crash.

Just by adding en-us windows language (from windows settings panel), the app doesn't crash anymore.

It's wired because the app only crashes on targets and not if a sideload the app on my dev PC (without en-us language)

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "Just by adding en-us windows language (from windows settings panel)," - I am having the same issue.

Comment: You need to open the windows settings menu, open the language menu and click on button "Add language". In the list displayed, select the item "English (United States)". This should avoid the crash of your app. It's not very beautiful but it works...

Comment: I found an other solution : you can just change your default project language on Package.appxmanifest. I change it to en-US instead of fr-FR...and this also works well.